# Rendering of <dl> displayed as list when embedded in <ol>

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

My CSS displays definition lists as bullets (I set the dt element to display:list-item and list-style:disc.)  I have a `<dl>` embedded within an `<ol>`.  IE10 renders this as I'd like -- a bulleted list inside my ordered list with no impact on the numbering.  However, both Firefox and Chrome count the embedded terms as items in the ordered lists.

For example:

```
<ol>
   <li> Fill out the fields: 
      <dl>
         <dt>First field</dt>
         <dd>This text describes the first field.</dd>
         <dt>Second field</dt>
         <dd>This text describes the second field.</dd>
      </dl>
    </li>
   <li>Do step two.</li>
</ol>
```

IE renders this as:

```
1. Fill out the fields:
   • First field
     This text describes the first field.
   • Second field
     This text describes the second field.
2. Do step two.
```

Firefox and Chrome renders this as:

```
1. Fill out the fields:
   • First field
     This text describes the first field.
   • Second field
     This text describes the second field.
4. Do step two.
```

How can I change my CSS to render this as desired in all browsers?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug , you need to make a reset of `display` on `dl` to avoid it :

```
    dl {
      display:table;
      /* or 
      display:flex;
      flex-direction:column;
or whatever acts like a block element but not block nor list-item
      */
    }
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/Gjxqf/)